# How to build a form from XML in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

**Update:**
I know *how* to parse XML, but not exactly where in the architecture, see problems defined below.
All suggestions are welcome!

---

Fighting my way into Laravel, I try to build a form from a XML file.

**Problems:**

1. how to get the data from the XML into the view?
2. *where* to build that form - in terms of repetition, I'd prefer to create the form once, and use it for create, edit and view
3. validation - I'd like to reuse it as much as possible

**the XML:** foods_form.xml (simplified):

```
<form>
    <field id="1" name="cheese" label="favorite cheese?" type="radio" req="1" filter="int">
        <option id="1" value="1">Camembert</option>
        <option id="2" value="3">Gouda</option>
    </field>
    <field id="2" name="beer" label="favorite beer?" type="text" req="1" filter="str" />
</form>
```

**the view:** app/views/create.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

<form action="{{ action('FormsController@handleCreate') }}" method="post" role="form">

    @foreach ($fields as $field)
        <label for="{{ $field->name }}">{{ $field->label }}</label>

        @if ($field->type == 'text')
            <input type="text" name="{{ $field->name }}" />
        @else
            @foreach ($field->option as $option)
                <input type="radio" name="{{ $field->name }}" value="{{ $option }}" />
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach    

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    <a href="{{ action('FormsController@index') }}">Cancel</a>
</form>
@stop
```

**the controller:** app/controllers/FormsController.php:

```
class TestsController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        // return some view
    }

    public function create() {
        return View::make('create');
    }

    public function handleCreate() {
        // validation according to XML
        // save to database if valid || return to form if not valid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a start on the type of class you could build to handle your XML to HTML form conversion.

```
<?php

class XmlToHtmlFormConverter {


    public function buildFormContent($filename)
    {
        $xml_fields = new SimpleXmlElement($filename, 0, true);
        $html = '';

        foreach ($xml_fields as $field) {
            $attributes = $field->attributes();
            $html .= '<label for="'.$attributes['name'].'">'.$attributes['label'].'</label>'.PHP_EOL;

            if ('text' == $attributes['type']) {
                $html .= '<input type="text" name="'.$attributes['name'].'" />'.PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $html .= $this->buildOptionInputs($field);
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }


    protected function buildOptionInputs($field)
    {
        $html = '';
        $attributes = $field->attributes();
        foreach ($field->option as $option) {
            $html .= '<input type="radio" name="'.$attributes['name'].'" value="'.$option.'" />'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        return $html;
    }
}

// Uncomment below to actually see the output, this works with your xml file.
// $converter = new XmlToHtmlFormConverter;
// echo $converter->buildFormContent('form.xml');
```

As a previous answer stated, you could inject this class into your controller constructor.
If you want to get fancy you can create an interface and inject that, then bind your implementation to that interface with App::bind('SomeInterface', 'SomeImplementation'); but to keep it simple you can just inject the class directly.

Controller:

```
class TestsController extends BaseController {

    protected $xml_to_html_form_converter;


    public function __construct(XmlToHtmlFormConverter $xml_to_html_form_converter)
    {
        $this->xml_to_html_form_converter = $xml_to_html_form_converter;
    }


    public function index() {
        // return some view
    }


    public function create() {
        $xml_file_path = 'some/path/xmlfile.xml';
        return View::make('create')->with(array(
            'form_content' => $this->xml_to_html_form_converter->buildFormContent($xml_file_path);
        ));
    }


    public function handleCreate() {
        // do your validations like you would with any html form
    }
}
```

And then your view would be like this...

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

<form action="{{ action('FormsController@handleCreate') }}" method="post" role="form">

    {{ $form_content }}

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    <a href="{{ action('FormsController@index') }}">Cancel</a>
</form>
@stop
```

Answer (score 5):

Laravel won't be helping you creating forms from some XML.

You'll need to parse your XML with a library like `SimpleXML` : you'll find some documentation [here, on php.net](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php)

Begin with creating a SimpleXMLElement :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('../path/to/your/file/foods_form.xml', 0, true);
```

You can now use your `$xml` object to generate your form, respecting the format of your XML (dump your `$xml` object to have an idea of the structure)

Simply put your object in your view to use it directly.

To validate your form, you can use `Validation` from Laravel : [link to the doc](http://laravel.com/docs/validation)

Comment: OK, I can parse the file. Coding that logic into the view seems not very MVC-like to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a class to parse `$xml` into an HTML form and inject it into your controllers via the constructor? Then your controller could do something like:  `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('../path/to/forms.xml'); $html = $this->xml_form_parser->parseToHtml($xml);`

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find an XSL friendly MVC.

The way I do it (Huge fan of XSL in views)

Final Page will have 3 modules lets say:

My view will only contain

```
// I don't know how you simply echo a variable from "yet another framework"
// but this is the only thing you need to do from the view
echo $someModule;
echo $otherModule;
echo $lastModule;
```

My controller will have 3 extra dependencies [injected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to contain whatever logic I got to execute. And use the simplest class to apply my xsl

```
<?php
class SomeController extends SomeMvcController {

    private $someModuleLogic;
    private $otherModuleLogic;
    private $lastModuleLogic;
    private $xslTransformer;


    public function __construct( XslTransformer $xslTransformer, $someModuleLogic, $otherModuleLogic, $lastModuleLogic ) {
        $this->someModuleLogic  = $someModuleLogic;
        $this->otherModuleLogic = $otherModuleLogic;
        $this->lastModuleLogic  = $lastModuleLogic;

        parent::__construct();
        $this->xslTransformer = $xslTransformer;
    }


    public function someAction() {

        /**
         * doStuff functions will take your parameters like get, post etc and return a DomDocument object
         * which can be programmatically calculated via PHP or generated by reading an XML file (or xml from any buffer)
         */
        $someModule  = $this->xslTransformer->transform(
            'myViews/modules/someModule.xsl',
            $this->someModeuleLogic->doStuff()
    );
        $otherModule = $this->xslTransformer->transform(
            'myViews/modules/otherModule.xsl',
            $this->otherModeuleLogic->doStuff()
    );
        $lastModule  = $this->xslTransformer->transform(
            'myViews/modules/lastModule.xsl',
            $this->lastModeuleLogic->doStuff()
    );        }
}



class XslTransformer {

    public function transform( $xslLocation, DOMDocument $domDocument ) {
        $xslDocument = new DOMDocument();
        $xslDocument->load( $xslLocation );

        $xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        $xsltProcessor->importStylesheet( $xslDocument );

        $document                     = $xsltProcessor->transformToDoc( $domDocument );
        $document->encoding           = 'UTF-8';
        $document->formatOutput       = true;
        $document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

        return $document;
    }
}
```

This keeps my views/controllers very small and simple without any logic. Everything is done in the injected class and I can chop that one into tiny simple pieces.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to XSL and will definitely look into it.